# Not able to change background colour of UITabbarcontroller iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uiappearance, xcode5.1

I've made subclass of UITabbar for my Tabbar 
Here is my Hierarchy UITabbarController->UINavigationController->UIViewController

Please look at this what I've done so far..I'm using window based Application to handle my App.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
// [self setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
// [self setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
 [self setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:123/255.0 green:47/255.0 blue:85/255.0 alpha:1]];
 //[self setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:227/255.0 green:180/255.0 blue:204/255.0 alpha:1]];
//[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.6]];
[self setTranslucent:NO];
}
```

Please help me out How can I get rid of it?Any suggestion
[image: Please have a Look]